# C# Casting generics type to right type

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I have this classes and interfaces:

```
public class XContainer
{
    public List<IXAttribute> Attributes { get; set; }
}

public interface IXAttribute
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface IXAttribute<T> : IXAttribute
{
    T Value { get; set; }
}

public class XAttribute<T> : IXAttribute<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

I need to iterate over  `XContainer.Attributes` and get property `Value` but I need to cast `IXAttribute` to correct generic representation like `XAttribute<string>` or `XAttribute<int>` but I don't want to use if-else if-else statement to check it like if `XContainerl.Attributes[0] is XAttribute<string>` then cast...

Is here a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way to do it.

Assuming you **want** to keep the current overall design, you could alter your non-generic interface and implementation as follows:

```
public interface IXAttribute
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    object GetValue();
}

public class XAttribute<T> : IXAttribute<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }

    public object GetValue()
    {
       return Value;
    }
}
```

Then your iterator would just access `GetValue()`, no casting needed.

That said, I think the design might not be the best for what you're doing.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you suggest better design?

Comment: Probably generics are just not a good fit for this. But we'd have to see more of the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

You could also define a generic extension method

```
public static class XAttributeExtensions
{
    public T GetValueOrDefault<T>(this IXAttribute attr)
    {        
        var typedAttr = attr as IXAttribute<T>;
        if (typedAttr == null) {
            return default(T);
        }
        return typedAttr.Value;
    }
}
```

Then you can call it with (assuming `T` is `int`)

```
int value = myAttr.GetValueOrDefault<int>();
```

The reason for implementing it as an extension method is that it will work with any implementation of the non generic interface `IXAttribute`.